# in what context is kaama positive

Tags: meaning

every positive energy/feeling is portrait as a deva and negative side is portrayed as an *asura* but *Kaama* is portrayed as a *deva*, meaning it has a positive aspect to it. But...

*Kaama* is not needed as a fuel for reproduction(those who see reproduction as a *kartavya* may accept it as it is) nor it has any place in love(I remember a line from somewhere where the protagonist tells, there is no place for kaama when there is love). Then, why is kaama needed and in what way is kaama positive/needed?

Comment: How do you decide that kaama is not needed for progeny. Dont forget kaama is also one of the main chatur purushartha. Kaama in general means desire. Not just lust.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi , duty is take with virakti and vairagya, desire would be quite the contrary

Comment: who says so ? Reference?

Comment: I think that is duty by definition else it not duty... and I do agree that Kaama is not lust, but can you please quote slokas for your comment above: "kaama is also one of the main chatur purushartha" and "How do you decide that kaama is not needed for progeny"

Comment: @juztcode I have added details on purushartha in my answer. Though good if you read whole para, but I have highlighted major points in bold part, reading that alone can give you idea.

Comment: @juztcode with kama how would you get erections?  Which is needed for a progeny?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi , I don't mean to argue in opposition, and don't have much reference to verify this: but isn't one aspect of meditation also to make conscious of your body allowing to to be aware and control it's functioning at will? e.g. yogis can control their blood pressure, and most probably other examples exist. But it is true that it would only allow to be able to do this  you'd have to be meditative which is not possible for everyone perhaps

Comment: @juztcode can you please elaborate further

Comment: @RakeshJoshi , as I've said I have no sources to verify this, but loosely speaking, one form of meditation is to be in total control of yourself. We know we can't control our emotions, our actions, our psyche and our spiritual interactions(some people might have some spirtual experience but they never and there is a physical basis to this as well. Once a meditator is at his peak he is in charge of what happens, when it happens, how it happens and is conscious of the entire process. Full conciousness in that regard doesn't need kaama or any supportive force to make changes within you.

Comment: @juztcode then there will be questions like whats need to eat or sleep etc. You are not clearly saying in your question if it is for general population or for some sadhaka. Nevertheless kaama would be there for a while. It doesn't mean that one should be into it throughout the day.

Comment: Kaama or indriya sukha is not copulation only, but all sense pleasures like eating delicious, intoxicating drinks, sleeping/lethargy, body luxuries, dominate others done with a body. No soul can become perfect yogi in one birth, hence reincarnation is needed. The goal is to know aatma which is not body and when atma is known by a yogi, what is the need of world, sense pleasures or even body for existence? The same gyan was given by Krishna to Arjuna during mahabharat. Its because of Maya alone a jiva needs wife, child, job for discipline,but a Sanyassi realizing Self/God renounces everything.

Comment: @ManuKumar , though you haven't mentioned what was asked in the question of kaama being positive

Comment: I explained to you kaama is for disciplining a jiva, for mindfulness and via concentration on material senses.http://www.ishwar.com/hinduism/holy_upanishads/brihadaranyaka_upanishad/part_03.html ' "It is that which transcends hunger and thirst, grief, delusion, old age and death. Having realized this Self, brahmins give up the desire for sons, the desire for wealth and the desire for the worlds and lead the life of religious mendicants ' Its purushartha, dharma(law) leads to artha(money), money leads to kama(sense enjoyments) and when kama is saturated one seeks Moksha(self-realization).

Comment: Buddha seeked enlightenment only when he had undergone marriage and kingship and saturation of senses. A beggar sensuous man who never experienced money and marriage in sufficient births can never become a yogi as his mind will wander in material things even he becomes a monk externally. A child is attracted to toys not an adult. An animal fights for senses but a yogi restrains them, while manhood is intermediate state where one can ascend to deva or remain man or descend to animal state based upon dominant Satva, Rajas and Tamas guna respectivally.

Comment: what about those who don't know kaama and don't seek it, who are by birth vairagis?

Comment: 'Rome was not built in a day', even though every one is aatma in reality, but not two individuals are  same because of different experiences from their previous several births, hence every jiva is unique, birth vairagis are rare like Jadabharata 'Gita 6.41 The unsuccessful yogis, upon death, go to the abodes of the virtuous. After dwelling there for many ages, they are again reborn into pious & prosperous family.Else, if they had developed dispassion due to long practice of Yog, they are born into a family endowed with divine wisdom. Such a birth is very difficult to attain in this world.'

Answer (score 7):

kaama is positive if used as meditative practice. It is mentioned in [verse 69, 70, 71 of Vijyanbhairava Tantra](https://www.thepathtoawakening.net/vijnana-bhairava-text.html):

> 69. During sexual union there is excitement and absorption in Śakti at the end. That joy, which is said to be the essence of Brahman, comes from the Self.
> 70. Divine Goddess, a man becomes flooded with joy at the memory of kissing, embracing, or having intercourse with a woman, even in the absence of physical contact.
> 71. On the occasion of great joy or on seeing a relative after a long time, by meditating on that joy, just as it arises, the mind becomes absorbed in That.

A good commentary is done by Yogi Matsyendranatha in [his Blog](https://matsyendranatha.com/?p=159). To understand the above 70 verse, I'll cherry-pick a para from his blog; which gives a clear perspective of this verse and meaning:

> The operative word is ‘recalling’ (smṛteḥ). It presupposes an earlier experience.  It is not fantasizing, or imagining what has not happened.  **It is not a form of pornography or voyeurism. It is not compensation or make-believe. It is the** ***act of recalling a delightful episode, which did in fact happen.***

Also in Dharmashastra, 4 Purushartha are mentioned which includes ***kaama*** too; they are **Dharma, Artha, Kaama and Moksha**. In the book [The Religious Traditions of Asia: Religion, History, and Culture, Page 17](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=5LSvkQvvmAMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=isbn:0700717625&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM5dLwyfLoAhXQzDgGHfiyBRQQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Joseph Mitsuo Kitagawa; He has explained these purushartha:

> **The Four Purusharthas (Goal of Man).** The theory that the integrated life involves the pursuit of four goals (arthas) is **first represented in the Dharmashastras** and the epics, in the latter case through repeated narrative illustration. The development of distinctive technical interpretations of each artha, or facets thereof, can also be followed during the period in separate manuals: **the Arthashatras** , a manual on statecraft attributed to Chandragupta Maurya's minister Kautilya but probably dating from several centuries later, **on arthaa (in the sense now of material pursuits) Kamasutra, most notably that of Vatsyanam (C 400 CE), on kaama("love, desire")** the already discussed Dharmasutras and Dharmashastras and the Sutras of the "philosophical schools" (darshanas) insofar as they are concerned with **the fourth goal, moksha**. **Early sources often refer to the first three goals as trivarga;** the three categories but this does not imply that the fourth goal is added later. **The Dharmashastras and epic texts that mention the trivarga focused on the concerns of the householder, - and in the epics, particularly of the royal householder these being the context of the pursuit of the trivarga. The fourth goal is to be pursued throughout life-- indeed throughout all lives.** but especially the goal of those who have entered the fourth life stage Sanyasin. The trivarga moksha opposition thus replicates the householder renunciant-opposition. But the overall purpose of the purushartha formulation is integrative and complementary to the varnaasharmadharma theory. **From the angle of the householder, it is dharma that integrates trivarga as a basis for moksha .**

Comment: Well compiled. Practical too

Comment: I don't quite get the fact, " It is the act of recalling a delightful episode, which did in fact happen." what does this specific sentence refer to?

Comment: @justcode it means remembering the time of making love with their partner which was pure.